# Python local imports still not working: ModuleNotFoundError or ImportError

Tags: python, module, python-import, importerror, file-structure

How can I import `src/constants.py` from within `src/data/compute_embeddings.py`?

#### Project structure

I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── data
│   └── raw
│       └── sample.xlsx
├── __init__.py
├── notebooks
│   └── clustering.ipynb
└── src
    ├── constants.py
    ├── data
    │   ├── compute_embeddings.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── embeddings.py
    └── __init__.py
```

#### Error

Now, within `src/data/compute_embeddings.py`, I try to import `src/constants.py`. Here is what happens when I run `python src/data/compute_embeddings.py`:

| Import method | Error |
| --- | --- |
| `from src.constants import ...` | `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` |
| `from ..constants import ...` | `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` |

I tried running as a module with `python -m src/data/compute_embeddings`, but I get `No module named src/data/compute_embeddings`.

#### Undesirable fix

I am however able to add `src` to `sys.path` and then my import works. However, I would rather not have to include `import sys` + `sys.path.append(...)` at the beginning of every file.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `src` should be treated as a directory that belongs on your Python search path, not the name of a Python package that your code can import.

Comment: So `from constant import ...` ?

Comment: Correct. The idea is that you install your code first. You can install your code as an editable package in a virtual environment to avoid having to modify `sys.path` (since now your code *is* in a directory that's on your built-in path) while still being able to make changes to you code without having to continually re-install.

Comment: You can also set `PYTHONPATH=src` in your environment so that when Python starts up, `src` is on the path without each script needing to update `sys.path` itself. I recommend using an absolute path rather than a relative path, in case the working directory can change between or during Python sessions.

Comment: Is it standard to pip install your own code when working on a simple project? I feel like a file should be able to import something from its parent folder, but I am by no mean expert on this topic.

Comment: It should probably be more *common* than it currently is, given how often people ask variations on this same question about accessing code stored in various places relative to the script they are executing.

Comment: There's a difference between organizing your code for *execution* and organizing your code for *storage* that doesn't get addressed often enough.

Comment: Not sure I fully get what you imply by storage vs execution, but that may be unrelated. Thank you for your comments anyway.

Comment: By storage, I meant where you put files in your working directory. The layout you use there doesn't need to be the same as the layout you would use to package your code.